# PHP Sum Array - sum only elemants of an array

Tags: php

I have have an array as follows:

`$row` when I output the entire array it produces the following:

`1.  I like crisps (38)     37% 55% 8%  0%`

When I `echo` one part of the array I get the 4 figures I am interested in.

`echo "<td class='set1'>". number_format($row[6], 0) ."%</td>";`

The above code outputs the following 4 numbers:

37% 55% 8%  0%

What I would like to do is simply ad the first two numbers together (i.e. 37% + 55%) and output the result (92%). Hope that helps?

I should also point out that the array contains much more information than just these four figures.

As requested: output from `var_dump[6]`

`string(7) "36.8421" string(7) "28.9474" string(7) "39.4737" string(7) "23.6842" string(7) "28.9474" string(6) "8.0000" string(7) "23.6842" string(7) "39.4737" string(7) "11.1111" string(7) "13.8889" string(7) "11.1111" string(7) "13.8889" string(7) "17.1429" string(7) "20.0000" string(7) "28.5714" string(7) "25.7143" string(7) "34.2857" string(7) "28.5714" string(7) "28.5714" string(7) "28.5714" string(7) "20.5882" string(7) "20.5882" string(7) "11.7647" string(7) "29.4118" string(7) "17.6471" string(7) "20.5882" string(6) "3.0303" string(6) "2.9412" string(6) "3.0303" string(7) "38.2353" string(7) "12.1212" string(7) "27.2727" string(7) "18.1818" string(7) "33.3333" string(7) "34.7826" string(7) "17.3913" string(7) "30.4348" string(7) "17.3913" string(7) "17.3913" string(7) "13.0435" string(7) "30.4348" string(7) "27.2727"`

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Homer.

Entire code - hope this helps:

```
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
do {
    /* store first result set */
    if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        $i = 1;
        while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            if($i==1){
            echo "<tr><td class='qnum'><span class='bold'>". $row[3] .".</span></td><td class='qtext'> ". $row[4] ." (<span class='italics'>". $row[5] ."</span>)</td><td></td>";
            $i = 0;
            }

            echo "<td class='set1'>". number_format($row[6], 0) ."%</td>";
            $var =  $row[6];
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        $result->free();
    }
    /* print divider */
    //if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
      //  printf("-----------------\n");
    //}
} while ($mysqli->next_result());
}
```

The section where $row[6] appears is where the four firgures 37%    55% 8%  0% appear - I would like to add the first two of these figures together.

If this helps, here's the result of the SQL query

```
response    q1  Responses   qnum    Question_Text   Total   percentage
4           4   14          1       I like crisps   38    36.8421
3           3   21          1       I like crisps   38    55.2632
2           2   3           1       I like crisps   38    7.8947
1           NULL    0       1       I like crisps   38    0.0000
```

The what I'd like to do is ad the 36.8421 and 55.2632 together.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you show us some code that you've written to implement the above? It might be easier to provide a solution that way.

Comment: Ok - here goes!

echo "<td class='set1'>". number_format($row[6], 0) ."%</td>";

The above code outputs the following 4 numbers:

37% 55% 8% 0%

What I would like to do is simply ad the first two numbers together (i.e. 37% + 55%) and output the result (92%).

Hope that helps?

Thanks in advance,

Homer.

Comment: Please, edit the question instead of commenting. Comments don't have formatting. Also, can you add the output of `var_dump($row)` or `var_dump($row[6])` to describe your data structure more accurately, for better responses.

Comment: @nikc - see above - yep, noted about placed code in the comments - I can also produce the dump for $row but be warned, there is loads and loads of data as the array is going through a loop - I thought it easier just to work on one iteration of the loop.

Comment: By the looks of it, you have one value per each row. (Presuming you're `foreach`-looping a collection.) Am I correct? What is it that you want to sum? Every two rows? As in `$rows[n][6] + $rows[n+1][6]`?

Comment: @nikc - I've updated the question adding my code and also the output from the SQL query - I hope this helps.  In answer to your question, yes I want to add the `$rows[n][6] + $rows[n+1][6]` but only the first stored number in each.

Comment: What is the logic behind the addition? Do you *always* add every two rows, or is there some other common denominator? By the looks of it, you'll need to iterate through the data once preparing it for output. (Which is a good idea anyway, since separating business logic from presentation is always a good thing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the assumption that you *always* want to sum *every two rows*, you could do it as follows:

```
// This for-loop is intended as a replacement for your 
// innermost while-loop (rows 6-14 in your question).
// I used a for-construct because we need to count the 
// cycles, and it will do it for us.
// The condition for terminating the loop is still the same
// as in the original while-loop.

?><tr><?php
for ($rownum = 1; $row = $result->fetch_row(); $rownum++) {
    if ($rownum == 1) {
        ?>
        <td class='qnum'><span class='bold'><?php echo $row[3] ?></span></td>
        <td class='qtext'><?php echo $row[4] ?> (<span class='italics'><?php echo $row[5] ?></span>)</td><td></td>
        <?php
    }

    // Sum and display on even cycles 
    // as <N> modulo 2 == 0 is true only on even numbers
    if ($rownum % 2 == 0) {
        // Display the formatted value,
        // at the same time adding the previous cycles value to this one
        ?><td class='set1'><?php echo number_format($tmp + $row[6], 0) ?>%</td><?php

    // Store the value of $row[6] on odd cycles
    } else {
        $tmp = $row[6];
    }
}
?></tr><?php
```

Comment: @nikc - thanks for taking the time but I'm not sure how the above would fit with my existing code - can't make sense of it I'm afraid.  Looking at it it isn't going to give me what I need.

Comment: @Homer: it is intended as a replacement for your innermost `while` loop. I added some comments to (hopefully) clarify my meaning.

Answer (score 7):

I imagine you could use a combination of [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) and [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
echo "First sum: " . array_sum(array_slice($arr,0,2));
echo '<br />';
echo "Second sum: " . array_sum(array_slice($arr,2,3));
```

Output:

```
First sum: 3
Second sum: 7
```

EDIT: based on the updated question, you would need something like:

```
$str = "55% 23% 12% 20%";

// the below line can be omitted because of the way PHP handles conversions
$str = str_replace('%', '', $str);
$arr = split(' ', $str);
echo "First sum: " . array_sum(array_slice($arr,0,2)) . '%';
echo '<br />';
echo "Second sum: " . array_sum(array_slice($arr,2,3)) . '%';
```

Output:

```
First sum: 78%
Second sum: 32%
```

Comment: I can't quite seem to get this work - I think the reason is I am working on a particular part of the array $row[6] - the above example is using the whole array $arr?

Unless I'm not understanding something correctly, which is very very likely!

Comment: @Homer_J - the above was intended as a self-contained working example. Just change `$arr` to `$row[6]` and it should be fine.

Comment: thanks for the note - I had tried with replacing $arr with $row[6] but it simply doesn't bring anything back, just blank.

Comment: thanks again for taking the time to reply but that doesn't work either - as I have more than just four figures stored in the array - hence that fact that I'm using $row[6] to get the fours figures from the array - but there is other stuff there as well.